# Dynamic form creation from XSD in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I know there is a lot of documentation on the internet as far as XSD to forms, but I have not been able to come across one that is straight forward enough for my situation.

I am working with a WCF web service that is going to fetch and .xsd xml schema, and must return the HTML of a form based on the .xsd xml schema. Is there any third party tools that can help out with this, if so what are they? If not, do you have any suggestions,better methods,etc for how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xsd is difficult to parse, but you can easily obtain a class from it, by calling xsd.exe /class or by doing it runtime following this beautiful sample:
http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/01/writing-your-own-xsdexe.html
hence with the classes representing your xsd you can use reflection to create the html code.

Comment: with this method, do you have any suggestions on how to use reflection to create the html code. I am knew to C#, and have never had any experience using reflection. If not, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: once you have the types generated by the xsd, you can use Type.GetProperties() to get single property names and types and use this for generating the html ...

Answer (score 4):

I am working on my own project called XsdFormEditor. Application will be able to show any XSD as a form in WinForms (95% done), Web (using Asp.Net MVC, 0% done), WPF (0% done). Idea is to load any XSD file, show it to user as a form, let user input some data and save data as XML. User will be also able to load default values to form from XML file. You can find it here: https://github.com/janstafa/XsdFormEditor

Comment: Thanks! This is very usefull for something I'm working on. Had to made some modifications to make it work for me though.

Comment: @TimGeerts good to hear that it helped you. if you made some improvements, please pull a request

Answer (score 1):

First of all, they will need not only to pass you the XSD (with no `include`, `import` or `redefine` elements in it), but will also need to tell you the root node.

Second, I would approach this by reading in the XSD with the [`XmlSchema.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.read.aspx) method. You could then loop through the object model pulling the information you need.

You might even try writing out an XML document containing the parts of the schema that you really need, and then running an XML Transform against it to produce the HTML.

Also, consider the Microsoft Office InfoPath product from Microsoft. Even if you don't wind up using the product itself, get a trial version to see how forms can be defined based on XSD plus other metadata.